# how to validate normal input with dynamic inputs Javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve that every time there is an empty entry, it warns me in an alert "there are empty fields" and also put the focus on an empty entry and so on until the last empty entry, if they are all full of data, the button says: "filled successfully", in an alert
it also has unique fields that must also be validated , what is the input id search

If the search field is empty, it should send an alert "there is nothing in the search" when pressing the button and also place the focus on the input

I have this problem with dynamic inputs. It is assumed that all entries with the txt name attribute
with the Add button, add these entries dynamically

for what is appreciated, it does not show the message "empty fields" every time the button is pressed.

Whenever an empty field is found, the focus should be placed on the empty entry.

If there are all entries with data, this should execute the message, all fields filled.

This is my code, below is the expectation (the second executable)

```js
// Constantes para el div contenedor de los inputs y el botón de agregar
const contenedor = document.querySelector('#dinamic');
const btnAgregar = document.querySelector('#agregar');

// Variable para el total de elementos agregados
let total = 1;

/**
 * Método que se ejecuta cuando se da clic al botón de agregar elementos
 */
btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `<label>${total++}</label> - <input type="text" name="nombre[]" placeholder="Nombre" required><button onclick="eliminar(this)">Eliminar</button>`;
  contenedor.appendChild(div);
})

/**
 * Método para eliminar el div contenedor del input
 * @param {this} e 
 */
const eliminar = (e) => {
  const divPadre = e.parentNode;
  contenedor.removeChild(divPadre);
  actualizarContador();
};

/**
 * Método para actualizar el contador de los elementos agregados
 */
const actualizarContador = () => {
  let divs = contenedor.children;
  total = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].children[0].innerHTML = total++;
  } //end for
};


function ValidarVacios() {
  var f = document.forms['form1'];
  var text = "";
  var alerta = false;

  for (var i = 0; i <= parseInt(f.numTexts.value); i++) {

    text = 'txt'
    if (([text] + '.value') == '') {
      alerta = true;
    }
  }
  if (alerta == true) {
    alert('empty fields');
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Inputs dinámicos</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" />

  <button id="agregar">Agregar</button>
  <div id="dinamic"></div>


  <input type="submit" value="Pik 1" onclick="javascript:ValidarVacios();">
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code, the expectation of what I want to do

```js
var counter = 0;
function addInput(divName) {
  counter++; 
  var Ai8ousa = document.createElement('div'); 
  Ai8ousa.innerHTML = "Field: "+(counter+1) + "<input type='text' name='field " + (counter+1) + "' id='field" + (counter+1) + "'>";   
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(Ai8ousa);
}

function validations(form) {
  var field;
  var i=0;
  do{
    field=form[i];
    if (field.value=='') {
      field.focus();
      alert('The field ' + field.name + ' is blank, please enter a value!');
      return false;
    }
    i++;
  } while( i <= counter);
  alert("everything is OK, submiting the form!");
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validations(this)" >
<input type="text" name="buscar" id="buscar" />

  <div id="dynamicInput">
    <div>Field : <input type="text" name="field 1" id="field1" /></div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="New field" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```